# Adding a variable to an ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am showing some properties of an ActiveRecord::Base called Micropost:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Creation Date</th>
    <th>Progress</th>
  </tr>

  <td>
    <% @user.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= micropost.content %></td>
      <td><%= micropost.created_at %></td>
      <td><%= micropost.progress %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</table>
```

This is the class definition:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
  @progess = 0
end
```

It works fine if I don't put the `<td><%= micropost.progress %></td>`. However, if I do I get a:

`undefined method`progress' for #`

I have also tried `progress :number` but I can't quite seem to find out how I can add a variable to that class and display it on my `.erb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@progress = 0` sets a class-level instance variable and does not create any methods. To create instance methods, use `def`, or one of `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader`, or `attr_writer`.